# automatically fill field in edit form sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have field that I want to automatize, I have department field is managed metadata, with different department, I want when I fill the editform, automatically , if department is IT then my field is NumIT0001 , the same for other department, have you any idea.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Usually calculated columns are used for such purposes.  However,  since you have a managed metadata column, calculated column cannot be used. You can use jquery/javascript in the form to read the metadata field value and set the other field.

Comment: Have any Link to guide me .

Answer (score 0):

Using `ItemUpdated` event receiver might help you.